Request failed with status code 401 AxiosError
I tried on Postman with the same token and body, everything were okay, but when I run my code it throw exception all the time.
Here is my source code
const AddScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
 
  const HandleAdd = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

    await axios
      .post(
        'https://kami-backend-5rs0.onrender.com/services',
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        },
        {
          body: JSON.stringify({
            name: name,
            price: price,
          }),
        },
      )
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.log);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <View style={{padding: 10}}>
        <TextInput
          value={name}
          onChangeText={text => setName(text)}
          style={{marginBottom: 20, borderRadius: 12}}
          label="Service name:"></TextInput>
        <TextInput
          value={price}
          onChangeText={text => setPrice(text)}
          style={{borderRadius: 12}}
          label="Service price:"></TextInput>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={HandleAdd}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Add</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
};
export default AddScreen;

I've tried with postman and everything was okay:


